# What is the purpose of the equation

Tags: quantum-chemistry

In my chemistry class we solved the equation wavelength = h/mv for finding the mass of a baseball and were given all of the other variables. I know that this equation has to do with wavelength of objects that contain mass but since objects with mass such as a baseball don't move constantly up and down in a wave pattern as they move towards something, they just arc down then what is the purpose of this? My teacher said it had something to do with waves emitted by the baseball or something like that but then why would it need mass?

Comment: How do you know that a baseball doesn't move constantly up and down? Maybe the waves are just so small you can't see them? Maybe the said wavelength has something to do with this? Maybe you should have found it? Maybe _you did_?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about chemistry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deBroglie wavelength of a particle: λ=h/mv

Yup - it seems to be for getting the wavelength of an electron or a proton.
https://www.thoughtco.com/definition-of-de-broglie-equation-604418
http://www.softschools.com/formulas/physics/de_broglie_wavelength_formula/150/

It's an entertaining equation to use with a baseball, though, even if it might not be a good application of the equation.

The baseball has 'huge' masses and velocities.  What sort of a wavelength will you get if you divide h by a 'huge' number?

Light can be either a wave or a [very very tiny] particle.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave–particle_duality - this wikipedia article talks about how, according to quantum mechanics, every particle also has a wave nature.

I hope that helps!